# Check a string and delete until find some text and complete after find other

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and i want to delete some parts of it. For example check the string and if it finds the `<!-- Start of comment -->` will delete that AND until founds the `<!--End of comment -->`

```
var myString = "<!-- Start of comment--> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<!--End of comment -->"
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that. What type of content can be inside the comments? If it is just text, you could use this

```
var regex = /(<!-- Start of comment-->)([^<]*)(<!--End of comment -->)/gim;
var resultString = myString.replace(regex, '');
```

This regex assumes that the string will not have any tags in it.